# How to Show Popup Menu On Listview Item Click?

Tags: android, listview

I want to **show popup menu every time i Click on listview items**. But its not working . Help me Out.
  But Toast Works Fine.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String[] mobileArray = {"Android", "IPhone", "WindowsMobile", "Blackberry",
    "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X"};

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,
    R.layout.activity_listview, mobileArray);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello Javatpoint", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, list);
    popup.getMenuInflater()
    .inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
    }
    });
    }

    }
```

Comment: You need to call `show()` on the popupMenu to actually show. Add `popup.show();` after inflating the menu items

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: "Isnt working" isnt a problem description that we could help with much. Be as specific as possible!

Comment: Thanks its Works Fine .

Comment: but it show the menu on bottom only. how can i show that in near to item i click.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
         Inside your listview  onitemclicklistener call this function:

```
      PopUp(); 

    private void PopUp() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Activity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.yourlayotu);


    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to show popup menu you need to use   `show()` of Popup menu